# Get user input and save it to up to three variables

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a problem with the following code:

```
cmd, arg, arg1 = input("> ").split(" ")
```

I want to get the input into these three vars.
But if I leave `arg` and `arg1` empty, Python complains:

> not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 1)

How can I avoid this?

I want to make `arg` and `arg1` optional.

Answer (score 7):

you cannot unpack into variables if the size varies. Well, not like this.

You can, using [extended iterable unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/) (also known as star unpacking) (Python 3 only):

```
cmd, *args = input("> ").split(" ")
```

now if you enter only a command, `args` is empty, else it unpacks the arguments you're entering into a list.

```
if not args:
  # there are no arguments
  pass
elif len(args)>2:
  print("too many args")
else:
  print("args",args)
```

note that you'll find `split(" ")` limited. I'd do `split()` (no argument: groups blanks to avoid empty args), or handle quoting with `shlex.split(input("> "))`

Note: with python 2, you'd have to split and test length. Less elegant, but would work.

Comment: This might seem confusing if you're starting out, but it's a very good answer.

Comment: thanks. Since OP knows about unpacking, that's just a step ahead :)

Comment: For memo, answer above is referencing [PEP 3132: Extended Iterable  Unpacking](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/).. which is pretty cool in my opinion.

@Chris, I don't think it's confusing. It's one of the first things I tried when I started learning Python (2.7) because it was "obvious" something like this would work, but it didn't.

Answer (score 2):

You can set the variables separately after getting the input string:

```
inp=input("> ").split(" ")
l = len(inp)
if l >= 1:
    cmd = inp[0]
if l >= 2:
    arg1 = inp[1]
if l >= 3:
    arg2 = inp[2]
```